# Wix Burn Rollback

Tags: wpf, wix, rollback, burn

Sorry if this is a bit vague, theres only so much information and im scratching my head as it is!
I am making a WPF installer, all going well so far, but iv found that if i cancel the installer, I would expect it to rollback, but in the burn log, it says:
"Skipped Rollback of package: .msi"
has anyone seen this? know why it skips?
Also, as a sidenote, is there a way to display in the progress bar, the percentage of rollback? (not important, just seemed topical to ask in the same question..)
Thanks for any help/contributions, sorry if this is a bit vague, really am confused why it skips the rollback :(

Chris

Answer (score 0):

It seems like its a time thing, i was cancelling after it got started a little bit (the installer it was skipping).
I had to add custom action rollbacks in and that solved the issue, ensuring everything got rolled back correctly. As for rollback percentage.. still no idea :(
any ideas, let me know. ta